# Polynomially many iterations of one way permutation

Tags: encryption, one-way-function

I have seen that the existence of weak OWFs implies the existence of strong OWFs.
It comes from repeating the weak OWF polynomially many times on *different* random inputs.

However, I have a different question here : given a weak one-way *permutation* $f$, does the function $(f\circ f \circ f \circ \dots \circ f)$, where the composition happens polynomially many times, have to be a *strong* one way function? The first result seems to say this is untrue, because something like this would have worked in the previous case as well, but I'm unable to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: I do know that this is not true if the composition happens only finitely many times. How do I use the "polynomially many times" to my advantage, or can I use it?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the weak one way permutation you're working with?

Comment: @back_seat_driver I don't know of any concrete examples/candidates for a weak one way permutation. For the moment, I think I know  that there exists a weak one way permutation that is NOT a strong one way permutation. From this ,  if I can get a statement of the following kind : If $f \circ f \circ ... \circ f$ is a strong OWF, then $f$ is a strong OWF as well, then I am done, right?

Comment: "If f∘f∘...∘f is a strong OWF, then f is a strong OWF as well." I don't think this is true generally. One way functions can be built with only reversible functions! Provided that you truncate/delete some of the information from the final output. It's hard to guess information you don't have despite the fact that it was produced.

Comment: @back_seat_driver All right. So then the question is, what am I expected to do? I am quite sure that if $f$ is a weak one way permutation that is not strong, then the resulting $g$ will only be weak and not strong. How would I show this?

Comment: I won't be able to provide you with formal maths, but there is a sub-function in the SHA-3 hash algorithm called theta, that from my experience is a good example of a weak one way permutation. Finding a working version of the function can be difficult so here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/back-seat-driver/d79d3c0f150acf597377641985b9de4b) to the code. If reversing this function will help you I can provide proof of work.

Comment: @back_seat_driver I appreciate your effort. However, I don't want a counterexample like the one you have given, since this question appeared to somebody as an assignment from a basic cryptography course, and the only given background was a good understanding of one way  functions and related theorems. So I feel  that there is a general candidate construction that will avoid this, rather than a hash function-related function, which is beyond the syllabus for that course. But thanks anyway.